# powershell write name of file containing string

Tags: string, search, powershell

I have following two lines in my Input file.

Sample Input file ( name of file - file.txt)

```
String1   value   'string2'
..
..
..
Call  string1
```

Desired output :
`File.txt`. ( i.e. Name of file )

Basically i want names of file - if it contains these two lines 
1) `string1 value 'string2'`
2) `call string1`

1) and 2) above are two different lines and there could be many lines in between.

P.S. a) i am searching for `'string2'` . `'string1'` could be any 8 characters. I do not know `'string1'`
b) `'string2'` will be always in single quote (')
c) `'string2'` will always be preceded by string `'value'`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
 gc input.txt |?{$_ -match '.*value ''(.*)'''}|%{$matches[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below script goes through each file in the current directory and looks for the files with the 2 lines in the content. Not sure if this meets your situation but it is not difficult to customize it to you environment.

```
dir *.* | foreach {if (get-content $_| Select-String -pattern  "^[A-Za-z]{8} value 'string2'","Call string1") {"$_"}}
```

The output (in my lab) is:

```
C:\Documents\ManualScripts\test.txt
```

test.txt is the file I created for testing this script. The content is as following:

```
abcdefgh value 'string2'
hello world
I love church
I love Jesus
call string1
Alibaba, sesame open the door!
```

To @dazedandconfused I believe your script return "String1" which is part of the second line instead of file name he/she requested. Besides your script doesn't reflect another one of his/her needs: "'string1' could be any 8 characters". Forgive me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I am almost there. Pardon my inexperience. Just a small change i would require - in your script. 'abcdefgh' (first line before 'value') should match 'string1' (after call statement in 5th line). In other words, string1 should be equal to 'abcdefgh' - then only i want it in Output. Thanks.

Comment: No problem I am newbie too for powershell. If it makes sense please accept the answer:)

Comment: Actually, the original post has been edited substantially.  My original answer was relevant at the time but not so much now.